# Android open DocumentPicker directly in Downloads directory

Tags: android

Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) describes very good how to use the new Document provider. But there is a problem, it says that we can specify the URI where we want the system chooser to start with by doing the following:

```
 putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
```

But the problem is that it does not tell anywhere what value should I use instead of `pickerInitialUri` to open system directories as **Downloads**, **Documents** atc.

So the question is, what is the correct way to get Uri for **Downloads** or **Documents** folders? Are there any constants for that?

Comment: I don't think that there are constants for that. The expectation that `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` is some previous `Uri` that you obtained from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: Which action do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXTRA_INITIAL_URI works for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT but not for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

You can put the uries of documents the user previous choosed.

For ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let the picker open on primary partion or de secondary (removable sd card) without using that extra. Only on Android Q+ i think.

There is nothing to let the latter open in the directories you want as far as i know.

Comment: This answer is contrary to the Android documentation at: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file  but it would seem to be the correct answer.  I couldn't get the document tree to open to a specific folder.

Comment: @user1608385 The times have changed. To open in a predetermined directory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-action-open-document-tree-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder/67554693#67554693

Comment: Yes.  That solution works for me.  If this solution breaks in a future version, I would hope that the Android team comes up with a standard reliable solution.